# unable to mount a NTFS SD card Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, sd-card

I want to access the SD card of my mobile. So I removed it from my mobile and connected it via SD card reader /USB with my kubuntu 18.04 PC.

```
$sudo fdisk -l
/dev/sdc1        32768 249737215 249704448 119,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

If I try to mount it I cannot get the matching type:

```
$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/anja/SD
```

complain about wrong type. What my kernel offers are the following types:

```
$ cat /proc/filesystems | awk '{print $NF}' | sed '/^$/d'
sysfs
rootfs
ramfs
bdev
proc
cpuset
cgroup
cgroup2
tmpfs
devtmpfs
configfs
debugfs
tracefs
securityfs
sockfs
dax
bpf
pipefs
hugetlbfs
devpts
ext3
ext2
ext4
squashfs
vfat
ecryptfs
fuseblk
fuse
fusectl
pstore
mqueue
autofs
rpc_pipefs
nfs
nfs4
```

What can I do to access my SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install these  tools and be happy:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

not even a restart is needed